# Switch connection not working

Tags: linux, networking, switch-statement, connection

Although some similar questions have been asked here, none of them seem to solve my problem, so I've decided to specify my case in a new question.

(Please keep in mind that I am a beginner in computer networks) I have 5 machines I want to connect to each other. I am using a switch to do so.
My first problem is that among 4 of the machines, 3 of them seem to have the same Broadcast and can hence communicate with each other. But 1 of them has a completely different broadcast and cannot communicate with any of the machines (although all 4 are connected to the same switch...). Note that all 4 machines have the Gentoo linux distribution.

Moreover, the fifth machine (which has Ubuntu linux distribution) doesn't even seem to have an ip assigned to itself. When I do "ifconfig" I don't get the eth0 interface but enp0s25 instead, where the inet addr is not specified.

I guess if I can determine the same broadcast in all 5 machines I will be able to obtain a propoer connection between the machines.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if your PCs are in the same network maybe that is the reason you have different broadcast  address. Check if your IP and Netmask are correct. Read this link for more information [IP Addressing and Subnetting for New Users](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/routing-information-protocol-rip/13788-3.html)

Example:

```
Network     -     Broadcast

192.168.1.0/24 -> 192.168.1.255

192.168.1.0/25 -> 192.168.1.127 

192.168.1.127/25 -> 192.168.1.255
```

In the examples look like all are in the same network but in reality are in different networks/sub-networks

About you eth0 check if your interface is using a static or DHCP IP.

check the configuration file:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```